# Illegal char <:> at index 44: com.example..myApp.app-mergeDebugResources-69:/values/values.xml

Tags: android, android-studio, compiler-errors

I can't build my app after adding this library [CrystanlRangeSeekBar](https://github.com/syedowaisali/crystal-range-seekbar) in my project.

I spend all the day but can't solve this problem. If anyone know know solution for this problem please help.
Thanks (Advance)

Check all the xml files but can't find any solution.